# Html tidy up in vim(windows) indentation and white space

Tags: html, vim

When I use gg=G on a angular html template file. Occasionally it leaves white space on line endings. But the big problem is the indentation it works as expected with html elements (2 space indentation). But we have a multi-attibute then multiline rule but the attributes don't indent and its a bit tiresome having to change the attribute indentation after doing gg=G.

The output I would like is the following :

```
<div
  class="test">
  <span
    class="testspan"
    data-ng-bind="vm.title">
  </span>
</div>
```

But what I actually get is :

```
<div
class="test">
  <span
  class="testspan"
  data-ng-bind="vm.title">
  </span>
</div>
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/othree/html5.vim does exactly what I needed and indents attributes when hitting gg=g